# How can I get the radiation effect Carto map

Tags: carto

I want to achieve the radition effect with Carto like this url https://carto.com/blog/telefonica/

[image]

Can I develop it with Torque.js?

Comment: You'll have to a be a lot more precise about what "radiation" is for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow quite a few steps, but you have a fully documented example here

https://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/8aeb48a274e3b787ca57

Basically, you need to compute the full circle lines, split them into points, assign them a correct identifier or timestamp and then use Torque to render that in the browser.

The SQL looks hard but it's just quite a few steps with a few postgis/postgres tricks.

Comment: @dtbelieve if this meets you requirements, please mark the question as answered by clicking the green tick under this answer.